# c# BitConverter.GetBytes(float/double) format?

Tags: c#

What output format does "BitConverter.GetBytes" generate? 
does it generate:
IEEE standard for normalized
   single/double-precision floating-point numbers
I need to know this as im writing a XDR communication and as described in [RFC 1014](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1014.html), 3.6 and 3.7 thay use the IEEE standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's IEEE. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) for example. The endianness may differ from system to system however, since that's not part of the the IEEE 754 specs. You can test against that with `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's IEEE 754. Basically that's the in-memory representation - at least in Microsoft's CLR - and `BitConverter.GetBytes(float/double)` just copies the memory directly into a byte array.